# Document classification with very few documents

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I wanted to know if there is any method in state of art that deals with document classification methods with very few training samples in R.

I have just 20 documents and need to classify them into 3 different classes.

I know it would be great to have a large corpus as part of the training data for every class, but the reality is that I have just 20. So I am assuming that approaches like topic modelling will have very little value add.

I am thinking of a simple approach like taking the term document matrix and running a logistic regression.

Wondering what others would like to suggest.

Comment: What kind of documents do you have and how long are they? Why you can't label/create more samples? This task is next to impossible to do right with machine learning (unless some task-specific trick can be invented, but that needs more info about your problem). People usually resort to hand-written classification rules for situations like that.

Comment: These are documents of around 8 pages length. I cannot get more documents as the source hasn't provided with more documents. I believe your suggestion of using a rule-based approach is a more feasible one.